# Regex optional substring

Tags: regex, pcre

I am having a hard time getting the right regex for the following

What I want: Three matches (John Doe, , Jane Doe)

The problems are the optional anchor tag and that there can be empty results.

String to search:

```
<td class="character">
  <a href=""> John Doe </a>

</td>
<td class="character">

</td>
<td class="character">
  Jane Doe 

</td>
```

My regex so far:
    `@<td class="character">.*?(?:<a.*?>)?(.*?)(?:</a>)?.*?</td>@gms`

Link to regex101 https://regex101.com/r/9NRhjI/1

I know you shouldn't use regex to parse xml/html, but as I only use it to dig through a tiny subset of html it should be possible, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Try this: `<td[^>]+>\s+(?:<a[^>]+>)?\s+([^<]+?)\s+(?:</a>)?\s+</td>`.

By the way, you should really have a look at @Zenoo's comment

Comment: Thanks alot @Saud this is working for me :)

Comment: @user2610665 Sure thing. BTW, I just improved it a bit, if you haven't noticed

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple regex:

`@<td[^>]+>\s+(?:<a[^>]+>)?\s+([^<]+?)\s+(?:</a>)?\s+</td>@gms`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/KLT7SQ/1)